# Можно ли создать сайт на flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Добрый день. Я программист Action Script 3.0. Могу ли я создать сайт(соц.сеть) на flash и с небольшим вмешательством php 5.

Comment: Здравствуйте, можете)

Учитывайте только тормознутость флэша и утечки памяти, если соцсеть будет отжирать гиг памяти - долго у вас не задержатся. Вообще странная идея, если честно.

А, ну и небольшим вряд ли получится.Если только движок брать и под себя переделывать.

Comment: Просто в моей соц.сети самое главное будет дизайн, но многофункциональность тоже необходима.

Comment: Ну так вопрос-то в чем?) Вам нужно, судя по всему, найти подходящий вам движок соцсети и до посинения превращать html в данные, какие вам нужны (xml/json/url). Соответственно с клиента шлем запрос, получаем данные etc etc

Comment: Создайте лучше собственную операционную систему :-)

Answer (score 1):

Можешь, конечно, но я думаю, будущее за SVG и Canvas, а не флеш, так как они уже в стандарте html5, а флеш изначально задумывался как костыль к html

Answer (score 1):

Не судите строго, но я предпочел бы использовать скрипты, а точнее библиотеку jQuery так как она(при прямых руках) может приподнятости хорошую визуальную часть Вашему сайту. Да и нагрузка будет уже(если это скрипт, то выполнятся на стороне клиента)только php скриптов.
Вот пример сайта на яве

> http://club.v-a-r.ru/

Comment: Просто оставлю это здесь - http://script.aculo.us/

Comment: karmadro4, Спасибо тебе большое!
Вот на этом сайте можно видеть малую мощь скриптов, они могут тягаться на ровне с flash по визуализации

Comment: Слитно и через **а**. На самом деле мощно было тогда, когда шесть(!) лет Гуччи переделали свой сайт (типичный флэш-сайт ранее) переделали на scriptaculous.

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё! Причем если технически правильно сделать. Это была бы одна из лучших соцсетей в мире.

Не слушай, кто говорит, что флэш тормознутый. Проблема не в технологиях, а в людях. Они не разбираются в вопросе.

Флэш, имеет ряд не оспоримых преимуществ. Возьми например, Вконтакте, там многие элементы сделаны на флэш(загрузка фото, плеер).